# Laravel query select with url variable in CONCAT

Tags: variables, laravel

I have this context in an Laravel (version 3.2) controller for rendering FullCalendar (a JavaScript event calendar from here: http://fullcalendar.io):

```
$url_edit = 'link';

$events = DB::query(DB::raw('SELECT bookmark_date as start, CONCAT(first_name," ",last_name) AS title, "false" as allDay, **CONCAT($url_edit,id_pacient) AS url** FROM bookmarks JOIN contacts WHERE bookmarks.id_pacient=contacts.id AND bookmarks.data >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH ORDER BY bookmarks.data ASC'));
```

The query is working fine without url parameters (the Calendar is generating OK).

But when I want to define url parameter in query, I have error if I insert the following syntax:

```
CONCAT($url_edit,id_pacient) AS url
```

If, instead of `$url_edit`, I put the string from variable `('link')` the Calendar is rendering normally.

Can you help me? How can I insert a variable in this query select?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just make a variable and paste your query string there.

`$sql = "your query string"`

then run your query like

`$events = DB::query(DB::raw($sql))`